# Docker vs node.js

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm fairly new to React-native. Im sorry about quite a convoluted question but I have dilemma. I am building an API that communicates with a server app that Im working on, I have been using Docker successfully to run containers BUT I'm constantly being told that I don't need to run Docker at all. I understand the principles of Docker and Node.JS but in all honesty I cant imagine how I would run server side without Docker. Ive tried Node.js and seemed to require a PHP server, which I was also told I did not need. Is this true? which is better Docker or Node.JS? and If Node JS is better how to run it without a php server as it is my understanding that php serves the pages and React consumes the pages.

Comment: You can [just install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), frequently through your OS's package manager.  It doesn't require PHP or other language interpreters.  I find working directly with Node much easier than using Node in Docker: it is actually a local development environment that my IDE is comfortable with, and not a path to run a Node interpreter "somewhere else" that's isolated from my desktop tooling.

Comment: "which is better Docker or Node.JS?" This is like asking, which is better - an apple or an apple in a ziplock bag? Docker by itself is not an alternative to node.js; you run node.js inside of Docker (or maybe you don't run node.js at all and run something else inside of Docker). It depends on what your goals are. Also, this isn't really a programming question. I suggest doing more background reading so you understand the basics of what Docker, node.js, and PHP are, and asking your question in a different forum.

Comment: Node is a framework for creating apps. Docker is one of ways to host such apps. Node can be just installed on a hardware and run, without Docker. Docker can be used to host not only Node but PHP, .NET Core etc. For some reason, though, there is PHP in your reasoning and PHP is neither Dorker nor Node. Thus, it's confusing what you are really up to.

Comment: John, docker is similar to your pc/laptop - which can run any software including application designed in node.js, PHP, python, java, etc. you can create a server using any of the programmings including node.js and run it on your laptop. so, your question is very naive.

Answer (score 2):

'You can just install Node, frequently through your OS's package manager. It doesn't require PHP or other language interpreters. I find working directly with Node much easier than using Node in Docker: it is actually a local development environment that my IDE is comfortable with, and not a path to run a Node interpreter "somewhere else" that's isolated from my desktop tooling. '

1)After a few weeks of research I found that I didn't need docker at all. Within Node is the ability to run a server using either fastify or express. I just needed to check on the relevant documentation for usage

2) I linked fastify to ngrok and exposed my local IP address to a public facing direction
3) I linked the ngrock url to my freedns and voila! it worked!
4) I had a small problem with the port which was resolved by using 
the command ngrok http 127.0.0.1:5000